# Photos on phone look VERY pixelated (sometimes) - but looks good on emulator

Tags: android, photos

I'm working on a news app that has one photo per article.  I'm resizing the photos on my server and DLing them to my app.

Everything looked fine then all of a sudden, I started noticing the photos on my phone looked VERY pixelated (not just kind of pixelated - they're like saving-a-jpg-at-0-quality crappy)  So I checked the emulator, and they looked fine - crisp/clean images.

Then later, the images on my phone looked good again, so I marked it off my to-do list "fix crappy-looking images on phone" - DONE.

Now, they're back again.  I've checked the URL that's resizing/supplying the photos - they look fine there.  I've tried different sizes, compressions...etc.  Currently, I'm at 90 quality, and 640 pixels wide.  I've tried 100 quality and 1200 pixels wide, and I've tried smaller as well.

My phone is a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Now the images look great again - pixel-perfect clean images.  No change to code. WTH?!

Comment: And back to crappy looking again - no change in code.